# Why is the crypt function not working here?

Tags: c, linux, crypt

I linked -lcrypt , the problems is that I get the same encryption no matter my command line argument. The encryption seems to only change if I change the salt. What in my code would lead to this flaw?

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE       
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char *enc[])
{
if (argc != 2)
{  
    printf("Improper command-line arguments\n");
    return 1;
}
char *salt = "ZA";

printf("%s \n", crypt(*enc, salt));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `crypt(*enc, salt)`, you're encrypting your *first* argument, which is the name of the program, not the first actual argument. Try `crypt(enc[1], salt)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You nearly got it. only the commandline argument handling was wrong.

if your program is called prg and you call it like this:

```
prg teststring
```

than `enc[1]` is "teststring"

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE       
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char *enc[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {  
            printf("Improper command-line arguments\n");
                return 1;
    }
    char *salt = "ZA";

    printf("%s \n", crypt(enc[1], salt)); // <<----

}
```

usually the command line args are called argc and argv:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

that would make the relevant line like this:

```
printf("%s \n", crypt(argv[1], salt));
```

Comment: Changing the first argument to enc[1] worked.... but I still dont understand this:                                                                       printf("%s\n", crypt ("drain", salt));                                  No matter the first argument, I get the same encryption, only changing the salt changes the encryption. Why is that?

Comment: @user3303819 - I don't understand your comment.